# Defining a literal as a multiple of another leads to wrong results

Tags: c, literals

Why does the following code gives wrong results when using a literal for 4*PI when it is used in the denominator as in `1.0/FOUR_PI`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define FOUR_PI 4.0*PI

int main() {
  printf("4.0*PI   = %.20lf\n", 4.0*PI);
  printf("FOUR_PI  = %.20lf\n", FOUR_PI);
  printf("4.0*PI - FOUR_PI  = %.60lf\n", 4.0*PI - FOUR_PI);
  printf("1.0/(4.0*PI) = %.20lf\n", 1.0/(4.0*PI));
  printf("1.0/FOUR_PI  = %.20lf\n", 1.0/FOUR_PI);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note; `4.0*PI` is not a _literal_

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that, when resolving the literal, its expression is replaced into the code, not its value. That is, `1.0/FOUR_PI` is being replaced by `1.0/4.0*PI`. See the following example to illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define FOUR_PI (4.0*PI)
#define FOUR_PI2 4.0*PI

int main() {
  printf("4.0*PI   = %.20lf\n", 4.0*PI);
  printf("FOUR_PI  = %.20lf\n", FOUR_PI);
  printf("FOUR_PI2 = %.20lf\n", FOUR_PI2);
  printf("4.0*PI - FOUR_PI  = %.20lf\n", 4.0*PI - FOUR_PI);
  printf("4.0*PI - FOUR_PI2 = %.20lf\n", 4.0*PI - FOUR_PI2);
  printf("1.0/(4.0*PI)  = %.20lf\n", 1.0/(4.0*PI));
  printf("1.0/FOUR_PI   = %.20lf\n", 1.0/FOUR_PI);
  printf("1.0/(FOUR_PI) = %.20lf\n", 1.0/(FOUR_PI));
  printf("1.0/FOUR_PI2  = %.20lf\n", 1.0/FOUR_PI2);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
4.0*PI   = 12.56637061435917246399
FOUR_PI  = 12.56637061435917246399
FOUR_PI2 = 12.56637061435917246399
4.0*PI - FOUR_PI  = 0.00000000000000000000
4.0*PI - FOUR_PI2 = 0.00000000000000000000
1.0/(4.0*PI)  = 0.07957747154594767280
1.0/FOUR_PI   = 0.07957747154594767280
1.0/(FOUR_PI) = 0.07957747154594767280
1.0/FOUR_PI2  = 0.78539816339744827900
```

Comment: *its expression is replaced into the code, not its value* That's how the preprocessor works, yes. Parenthesis are your friend.